# How to deploy a self-contained web app in a single instance without downtime?

Tags: deployment, web-deployment

I'm currently experimenting about building a self-contained web app that runs with embedded server. To run the app is just simply by executing

```
java -jar application.jar -Dserver.port=80
```

The thing is, starting the application from executing the line above until it can really listen to incoming requests needs a lot of time. In the sample above, I'm using Java's Spring Boot example, but it can be other libraries or other language.

With that problem above, deploying by killing the current server PID, symlink the new artifact, and then running the new artifact will have a slight downtime.

Another constraint is that, I can only have one instance at one time. So provisioning a new instance then deploying the new artifact into the new instance and then switch the instances from the load-balancer is out of question.

So, how do I do this?